# edt emulation - space bar isn't working

Tags: key-bindings, osx

While I used to use the TPU EDT emulation, this seems to be deprecated in the latest GNU emacs. Is this still available anywhere?

As a result I'm presently using the edt emulation directly. This works for most keys, except that the space bar isn't working. Is there a way to restore this while using the edt emulation? I'm running emacs on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

TPU-EDT was marked obsolete in Emacs-24.5, indeed.  That doesn't mean you can't use it.  It's still there (e.g. `(require 'tpu-edt)` should work just as well as before), tho it means it will probably be removed at some point in the future, such as in Emacs-27. for example.  If you'd like to see it live longer, I suggest you lobby the Emacs maintainers so that instead of removing it in some future version, it gets moved to GNU ELPA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. With TPU I had omitted the (require 'tpu-edt) line since in Emacs 23.1.1 it didn't seem to be needed. Now though with version 25.1 I'm using both lines below in my .emacs file and it works great!

(require 'tpu-edt)
(tpu-edt-on)

I'll try contact some of the emacs folks about future support, perhaps John Wiegley? TPU works much better for me than the direct edt emulation.